# Still trying to understand object oriented programming in Java

Tags: java

Assuming there is a class named Hello, How would I declare variables named var1 and var2 to be references to objects in the class Hello? 
I assumed it would just be Hello var1, var2;

Also to just construct an instance of the object of the class Hello using the default constructor would it just be Hello hello = new Hello();

Finally my last question is if I were to instantiate an object of the class Hello using the default constructor and assign that object to the varaible named var1 it would just be Hello var1 = new Hellow();. How would I assign the reference to the object named var1 to the variable named var2

And I know there is a term to describe the current state of the variables var1 and var2, but I cannot think of it

Comment: `Hello var2 = var1;`

Comment: is that just a shallow copy?

Comment: That's not a copy at all. The two variable will point to the same object.

Comment: Just a link to expand on what Thilo said : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value#answer-12429953)

Comment: Aren't there enough basic java tutorials on the web?

Answer (score 0):

Just given test example to illustrate the things

```
public class Hello {
    Hello var1, var2;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Hello h1 = new Hello();
        h1.var1 = h1;
        System.out.println("h1.var1 ---- "+ h1.var1);

        Hello h2 = new Hello();
        h1.var2 = h2;
        System.out.println("h1.var2 ---- "+ h1.var2);

        h1.var2 = h1.var1;

        System.out.println("h1.var1 ---- "+ h1.var1);
        System.out.println("h1.var2 ---- "+ h1.var2);
    }
}


    Output :- 

    h1.var1 ---- Hello@19e0bfd
    h1.var2 ---- Hello@139a55
    h1.var1 ---- Hello@19e0bfd
    h1.var2 ---- Hello@19e0bfd
```

> Assuming there is a class named Hello, How would I declare variables
>   named var1 and var2 to be references to objects in the class Hello? I
>   assumed it would just be Hello var1, var2;

You can see there are two variables declared of same class which can be reference  to `Hello` class instance.

> Also to just construct an instance of the object of the class Hello
>   using the default constructor would it just be Hello hello = new
>   Hello();

Yes there is default constructor associated with each class so you can do initialize class like this.

> Finally my last question is if I were to instantiate an object of the
>   class Hello using the default constructor and assign that object to
>   the varaible named var1 it would just be Hello var1 = new Hellow();.
>   How would I assign the reference to the object named var1 to the
>   variable named var2

As you see the output the hash code of `var2` is same as `var1` after `h1.var2 = h1.var1` statement. This states that `var2` previous reference is replaced by `var1` reference. So here objects are not copied but references to objects are copied. Check the same `hashcode` of `var1` and `var2`.

Thats it!.